# Strange behavior after cloning GitHub wiki

Tags: git, github, wiki

I had always assumed you couldn't clone a GitHub wiki. Today however I noticed the **Clone URL** button at the top of a wiki page, so I thought I'd try cloning the wiki.

To my puzzlement, after cloning, there are these weird untracked files which I assume are actually folders containing the wiki content. It's not possible to cd to these folders, but they open as blank text files.

When I deleted one locally, `git status` indicated that all of the .md files for that particular category had been deleted (as one would expect when deleting a folder). Here is the project link in case you want to see for yourself:

> git clone https://github.com/codalab/codalab.wiki.git

Has anyone else encountered this? I'd love to be able to clone the wiki repository and take advantage of all that Git goodness.

Comment: There are no untracked files after cloning this repo. You should be able to take advantage of all that Git Goodness, I clone wikis too and everything works as expected.

Comment: It worked for you? So you can `cd Dev` and see all of the .md files in there? Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I clone from that URL on Linux, I get the following files (there are no subdirectories):

```
Current-Comps.md
Dev:-Code-checkers.md
Dev:-Configure-CodaLab-for-Development.md
Dev:-Database-Migrations.md
Dev:-Deploying-CodaLab.md
Dev:-Developer-Guidelines.md
Dev:-Executing-jobs-on-Windows-and-Linux.md
Dev:-Getting-Started-on-UNIX-based-Systems.md
Dev:-Getting-Started-on-Windows.md
Dev:-How-to-Contribute.md
Dev:-Issue-tracking.md
Dev:-Scenarios,-Stories-and-Tasks.md
Dev:-Scenarios.md
Dev:-Settings-and-Configuration.md
E-mail-notifications.md
Home.md
Serving-data.md
Test:-Create-a-Windows-Azure-Ubuntu-Virtual-Machine.md
Test:-Debugging-CodaLab.md
Test:-Deploy-to-a-VM-in-Azure.md
Test:-Running-CodaLab-from-Git-on-Linux.md
Test:-Running-against-a-local-SQL-server-instance.md
Test:-Update-a-Windows-Azure-Ubuntu-Virtual-Machine.md
UX:-Progressive-Registration.md
UX:-UX-To-Do's.md
User:-Building-a-Competition-Bundle.md
User:-Building-a-Scoring-Program-for-a-Competition.md
```

On Linux, `:` is not a special character as far as the filesystem is concerned; it's just part of the file name.

I believe that Windows does not permit the `:` character to be used in file names (it's part of the syntax for volume names, as in `C:\`), so when `git clone` creates such a file, Strange Things Happen.

If you just want to clone it on Windows and take a look at it, I've created a clone [here](https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/codalab-wiki) with the file names changed. This is *not* intended to be a functional copy of the Wiki (I don't know whether or how the Wiki depends on the ':' characters in the file names), nor do I intend to maintain it.

Comment: @willum070: I've created a clone with Windows-compatible file names. See the last paragraph of my updated answer.